# Determine how many paths exist from $A$ to $B$ that > travel only to the right and up.

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

> In the picture below, you see a schematic of some of the streets in a
>   certain town. Determine how many paths exist from $A$ to $B$ that
>   travel only to the right and up. Two such paths are given in the
>   figure, one using a dashed line and one using a dotted line (they
>   overlap in multiple places).

So basically, you can only travel up and right only.

[image]

So what I decided to do was create some dots.

[image]

Basically, I said the number of paths(P) is equal to the combined totals of path going through each point.

So :

P=(# of paths from A $\rightarrow$ V $\rightarrow$ B)+(# of paths from A $\rightarrow$ W $\rightarrow$ B)+(# of paths from A $\rightarrow$ X $\rightarrow$ B)+(# of paths from A $\rightarrow$ Y $\rightarrow$ B)+(# of paths from A $\rightarrow$ Z $\rightarrow$ B)

Then, I started calculating each part individually. I said (# of paths from A $\rightarrow$ V $\rightarrow$ B)=$15$

and (# of paths from A $\rightarrow$ W $\rightarrow$ B)=$30$

but then I realized that these numbers are too big and I must doing something wrong. If anyone wants to know how I am calculating, this is how:

(# of paths from A $\rightarrow$ W $\rightarrow$ B)=(# of paths from A $\rightarrow$ W) *(# of paths from W $\rightarrow$ B )

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that there are paths that go through more than one of the dots, so would be over counted using your method. The answer below shows an easy way to calculate this without overcounting.

Comment: @SE318 oh i see, that makes sense

Comment: If you wanted to use your method, it is definitely possible. The principle of inclusion-exclusion gives you a way to compensate for the over-counting that you did. The solution below is much simpler though.

Comment: Using my hint you can find: $P_V=\binom22\binom62=15$, $P_W=\binom32\binom52=30$, $P_X=\binom42\binom42=36$, $P_Y=\binom52\binom32=30$ and $P_Z=\binom62\binom22=15$ where $P_U$ denotes the number of paths $A\to U\to B$ for $U\in\{V,W,X,Y,Z\}$. But as @SE318 remarked: summation overcounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$8$ moves have to be made. $4$ up and $4$ to the right. So you must select $4$ out of $8$ to be the upward moves. The other moves are automatically the moves to the right.

The two examples are $RURRURUU$ (dashed) and $RRUUURRU$ (dotted).

So it comes to calculating the number of ways $4$ items can be selected from $8$.

Comment: for RRUUUURRU, i think you meant RRUUUURR. So to calculate I did, $\frac{8!}{4! \times 4!}$ and got $70$ but that seems too high as well. am i doing it right?

Comment: Yes, you are doing right. I repaired the typo you mentioned.